# How do I display what I've written in the text input field upon clicking button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging

I want to display all the things that have been added when clicking `<Button/>` one by one but it isn't working.  I've tried adding a boolean state `showing` with the intentions of triggering it in order to display what it needs to display but I had no luck.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Here's `List`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Input from '../../containers/Input/Input';
import Button from '../../containers/Button/Button';

class List extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            value: '',
            showing: false

        };

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({value: event.target.value});
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        this.setState({value: event.target.value});
    }

    displayName = () => {
        if(this.state.showing) {
            return (
                <li>{this.state.value}</li>
            );
        }
    };

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <Input onchange={this.handleChange} />
                    <Button clicked={() => this.displayName()} />
                </form>
                {this.displayName()}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default List;
```

Here's `Input`:

```
import React from 'react';

const input = (props) => (
    <div>
        <input type="text" onChange={props.onchange}/>
    </div>
);

export default input;
```

Comment: Can you please also show your `Input` component? To make sure, is the `onchange` prop to it correct, rather than passing `onChange`? Also, you never set `showing` to `true` anywhere, so `displayName` is always going to return empty. Finally, why do you change the value `handleSubmit` when it has already been changed by by the `handleChange`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Input from '../../containers/Input/Input';
import Button from '../../containers/Button/Button';

class List extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            value: '',
            showing: false,
            latestValue: ""


        };

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({
            value: event.target.value,
            showing: false,
        });
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        this.setState({
            showing: true,
            latestValue: this.state.value
        });
    }


    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <input onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                <button onClick={this.handleSubmit}></button>
                <div>
                    {this.state.showing? this.state.value : this.state.latestValue}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default List;
```

You can try this one. I hope it helps.

Comment: I had something like this earlier.  I tried your way but it displays letters at every time you press a key.

Comment: nice, it works.  but now when I delete the text field, the displayed name also gets deleted.  how do I keep the displayed name showing?

Comment: @sp92 try again